# Accelerated SVM training for HOG algorithm

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

Let's say I have a perfect 3D model of the rigid object I am looking for.

I want to find this object in a scene image using the histogram of oriented gradients (HOG) algorithm.

One way to train my SVM would be to render this object on top of a bunch of random backgrounds, in order to generate the positive training examples.

But, is there a faster, more direct way to use the model to train the SVM? One that doesn't involve rendering it multiple times?